# NSTimer in 2 Views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, nstimer

I've got an NSTimer that counts up in one view, when I go to another view I want that the Timer continues counting up?
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved the problem: I've done:

```
-(IBAction)go {

NinthViewController *screen = [[NinthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
screen.nextTime = self.actualTime;
[self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
[screen release];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

since you want to use it in different classes, Why don't you put it in a more global class, like the AppDelegate, for example? That way you could access it from any class you wanted.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure Francisco's is the best (or the worst), but if the Timer is not meant to be application-wide, I would probably make sure the view responsible for the Timer keep the Timer.

Why not just store the timers' progress when leaving the view and loading the progress when you open the view again. Ofcourse you need to take the time difference between closing and opening the view and add that to the timer.

If I am wrong, just let me know, because this is the way I am doing it now.

Comment: Yes, I thought of this way, too. But how can I store the timer's progress when leaving the view? That's my real problem. I asked the question wrong.

Comment: store it in NSUserDefaults. This way it can also survive exiting the app.